# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.image_classifier'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

trying to run it this error is coming repeatedly nothing is working
the following is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-86f6d90695b7> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
----> 4 from utils.image_classifier import ImageClassifier, NO_FACE_LABEL
      5 
      6 # Color RGB Codes & Font

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.image_classifier'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to install some package or other.  The import statement is looking for a python module (script file) called "image_classifier.py" in a sub-folder called "utils" somewhere in your path.  That module needs to contain the class definition for ImageClassifier objects and what looks like a constant (variable assignment) called NO_FACE_LABEL.

I did a quick google but I couldn't find the package that might contain that module.  Are you aware of any pre-requisites for your code, things you need to have installed before you start?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install utils
```

If you've done it and it is still not working, you need to perform a search for "utils.py", and run your script on the same folder as in the "utils.py".